# Production Node Application Can't Find SVG Files

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, svg, express

In my local development application the svg files show up just fine with the following code (The curly brackets embed Angular.js variables):

```
<img ng-src="img/servant_{{servant.personality}}.svg" draggable="false">
```

But when deployed on Heroku, the SVG files result in a 404:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

The Angular variable is working on the Production site and the image addresses are accurate.  So, that's not the problem.

Instead, I think my Node/Express application might not be able to serve SVG files.  Perhaps it's a Heroku issue?  FYI I'm using the MEAN stack.

Here is the configuration of my public folder:

```
 //Setting the fav icon and static folder
        app.use(express.static(config.root + '/public'));
```

The images are in

```
public/img
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you load other images (including those of other types like .png) from the same directory?

Comment: Yes, I'm currently loading pngs and jpegs

Comment: Do you have a properly configured 'public' directory where static content can be served?

Comment: Just added the config of my public folder to the OP.  And yes, it's all working on my dev app.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but maybe it needs to be converted to a string or buffer before being sent?

Comment: try just using some basic node.js (no express or anything) to make a very simple sample server that JUST reads and displays the data of the file, and see if that works to help narrow down the cause of the issue

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have the correct mime-type configured to serve SVG files. Some servers simply respond with a 404 if the mime for the requested file type is not set.

image/svg+xml